# Removing Elements from numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following code for calculating the trajectory of a particle travelling downwards:

```
c = -299792458
q = -1
m = 0.002
v_x = 0
v_y = 0
v_z = c*0.994
  
x_i,y_i,z_i = 1,1,100
v_xi,v_yi,v_zi = 1,1,v_z
  
h = 1e-12
timesteps = list(range(1,int(4e5)))
x,y,z = x_i,y_i,z_i
v_xi,v_yi,z_yi = v_xi,v_yi,v_zi
  
height = 1
radius = 0.1
  
B_r = 12
Vol = 0.790524
B = lambda x,y,z : (B_r*Vol)/(4*np.pi*np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2 + z**2))
B_x = lambda x,y,z : B(x,y,z)*(3*z*x)
B_y = lambda x,y,z : B(x,y,z)*(3*z*y)
B_z = lambda x,y,z : B(x,y,z)*(2*z**2 - x**2 - y**2)
  
def F_x(x,y,z,v_x,v_y,v_z):
  return((q/(m*c))*(v_y*B_z(x,y,z) - v_z*B_y(x,y,z)))
  
def F_y(x,y,z,v_x,v_y,v_z):
  return((q/(m*c))*(v_z*B_x(x,y,z) - v_x*B_z(x,y,z)))
  
def F_z(x,y,z,v_x,v_y,v_z):
  return((q/(m*c))*(v_x*B_y(x,y,z) - v_y*B_x(x,y,z)))
  
p = np.zeros((len(timesteps)+1,3))
p[0,:] = [x_i,y_i,z_i]
  
v = np.zeros((len(timesteps)+1,3))
v[0,:] = [v_xi,v_yi,v_zi]
  
for i in range(len(timesteps)):
  p[i+1,:] = p[i,:] + h*v[i,:]
  v[i+1,0] = v[i,0] + h*F_x(*p[i,:],*v[i,:])
  v[i+1,1] = v[i,1] + h*F_y(*p[i,:],*v[i,:])
  v[i+1,2] = v[i,2] + h*F_z(*p[i,:],*v[i,:])
  if p[i,2]<0:
      break
```

My code generates a numpy.ndarray object p of shape (400000, 3) containing the coordinates of the particle. I would like to keep only the elements of it where the z-coordinate p[i:2] is above zero, and so to remove the element with p[i,2]<0 and all the [0,0,0] elements after it.

I tried using the following code:

```
for i in p:
  if p[i,2]==0:
    np.delete(p,1,i)
```

but I get "IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type". If someone could tell me how to deal with this error or some alternate code I can use to do what I want I'd appreciate it.

Comment: think in terms of selecting some elements instead of deleting others.  Even `np.delete` actually returns some values.

Answer (score 0):

The line `np.delete(p,1,i)` is wrong in multiple ways. Read the documentation.

Try instead

```
mask = p[:, 2] != 0
p = p[mask]
```